# How to set a fixed position and freeze my breadcrumb in the body of the HTML?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

How to set a fixed position and freeze my breadcrumb in the body of the HTML below, so it will not scrollable?

```
 <body>

     <div class="c-subheader justify-content-between px-3">
        <!-- Breadcrumb-->
        <ol class="breadcrumb border-0 m-0 px-0 px-md-3">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">x</li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">y</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">z</li>
            <!-- Breadcrumb Menu-->
        </ol>
    </div>
```

in my _layout.cshtml

```
    <div class="c-body">
        <main class="c-main">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can use css `position:fixed;` property with `top:0;` `left:0`; on `.c-subheader` element.

Answer (score 0):

**use this bootstrap4 class if you are using bootstrap4**

```
<div class="fixed-bottom">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your fixed position doesn't work because you haven't applied `top right bottom left`. Try this.

```css
.c-subheader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="c-subheader justify-content-between px-3">
  <!-- Breadcrumb-->
  <ol class="breadcrumb border-0 m-0 px-0 px-md-3">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">x</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">y</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">z</li>
    <!-- Breadcrumb Menu-->
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: all of the above answers are not working, perhaps I have to mention that I use ASP MVC Net Core, in my _layout.cshtml contains the following:

div class="c-body">
            <main class="c-main">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
        </div>

I have updated my question

Comment: I'm not sure. You must add your css and html code. More details